# R: For a list of dfs, filter for a value in Column1, to extract mean and SD of another Column2 (only of rows with the filtered value in Column1)

Tags: r, subset

I have a big dataset ('*links_cl*', each participant of a study has several 100 rows), which I need to subset into dfs, one for each participant.
For those 42 dfs, I then need to do the same operation again and again. After spending half a day trying to write my own function, trying to find a solution online, I now have to ask here.

So, I am looking for a way to

1. subset the huge dataset several times and have one in my environment for every participant, without using the same code 42 times. What I did so far 'by hand' is:

   `Subj01 <- subset(links_cl, Subj == 01, select = c("Condition", "ACC_LINK", "RT_LINK", "CONF_LINK", "ACC_SOURCE", "RT_SOURCE", "CONF_SOURCE"))`
2. filter for Column 'Condition' (either == 1,2,3 or 4), and describe/get the mean and sd of 'RT_LINK', which I so far also did 'manually'.

   `Subj01 %>% filter(Condition == 01) %>% describe(Subj01$RT_LINK)`

But here I just get the description of the whole df of Subj01, so I would have to find 4x41 means by hand. It would be great to just have an output with the means and SDs of every participant, but I have no idea where to start and how to tell R to do this.

I tried this, but it won't work:

```
   subsetsubj <- function(x,y) {
     Subj_x <- links_cl %>% 
       subset(links_cl,
              Subj == x,
              select = c("Condition", "ACC_LINK", "RT_LINK", "CONF_LINK", "ACC_SOURCE", "RT_SOURCE", "CONF_SOURCE")) %>% 
        filter(Condition == y) %>% 
       describe(Subj_x$RT_LINK)
    }
```

I also tried putting all dfs into a List and work with that, but it lead to nowhere.
If there is a solution without the subsetting, that would also work. This just seemed a logical step to me. Any idea, any help how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to split the dataset up into one dataframe for each patient. I would recommend a standard group_by()/summarize() approach, like this:

```
links_cl %>% 
  group_by(Subj, Condition) %>% 
  summarize(mean_val = mean(RT_LINK),
            sd_val = sd(RT_LINK))
```

Output:

```
    Subj Condition mean_val sd_val
   <int>     <int>    <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1         1   0.0375  0.873
 2     1         2   0.103   1.05 
 3     1         3   0.184   0.764
 4     1         4   0.0375  0.988
 5     2         1  -0.0229  0.962
 6     2         2  -0.156   0.820
 7     2         3  -0.175   0.999
 8     2         4  -0.0763  1.12 
 9     3         1   0.272   1.02 
10     3         2   0.0172  0.835
# … with 158 more rows
```

Input:

```
set.seed(123)
links_cl <- data.frame(
  Subj = rep(1:42, each  =100),
  Condition = rep(1:4, times=4200/4),
  RT_LINK = rnorm(4200)
)
```